# Need help in converting Azure Powershell to CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am very new to Azure CLI and having problems in converting the following command

Set-AzCognitiveServicesAccount -ResourceGroupName rg-xxx -Name cs-xxx -DisableLocalAuth $false

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and received same error as you have as below and I followed [Microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cognitiveservices/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cognitiveservices-account-update):

```
az cognitiveservices account update --name YY -g XX --disable-local-auth $false
```

[image]

XX- Name of resource group
YY- Name of cognitive service

The above error states that `az cognitiveservices account update` command does not support argument `--disable-local-auth` .

This command only supports `--name`  `--resource-group`  `--api-properties` `--custom-domain`  `--encryption`  `--sku` `--storage`  -`-tags`  arguments.

Alternatively, you can use [Rest-Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-manage-rest#preview-enable-azure-role-based-authentication-for-data-plane) to enable or disable local auths.